# tiki wiki how to permanently hide a tracker plugin from a user once saved

Tags: tiki-wiki

I'm trying to implement a read confirmation in a number of wiki pages.
I'm trying to use trackers.

**General Description**:

Employees in our company are assigned to read a number of official procedures.
I'm trying to implement a process where:

- Each employee is assigned procedures he needs to read according to his department (Group).
- Each procedure is a wiki page
- At the end of each procedure there will be a confirmation form in the following [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V3mX.png).

  - Users that don't need to read this procedure won't see this form.
  - Users that confirmed reading the document will see a message like:

    > You've confirmed reading this procedure.
- Administrators will be able to monitor who read what procedure.

**Questions**:

1. How do I hide the tracker plugin from users who don't belong to the department (Group)
2. How do I display a different message once the user confirmed the read

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are different way to achieve this and it require a bit of thinking (trade-off from a method to another), but this is what I’ll do.

Have 2 groups (before approving - after approving)
Display the procedures using a plugin listExecute and having at the end the approving checkbox to have some actions (notification, group changes, etc).

Enclosing everything in a tracker and turn it into a multipage forms can also be the way.

Your case remind me other use case I worked on including Official Procedures reading including quick test (to check if the procedures were understood) and approving mechanism. Look at https://doc.tiki.org/PluginExercise ;)

Good luck
Bernard
https://www.facebook.com/bsfez

Answer (score 0):

Another, possibly simpler (? ;) way to do that would be to use just plugins group and list, maybe like this:

```
{GROUP(groups="This Department")}
  {LIST()}
    {filter type="trackeritem"}
    {filter field="tracker_id" content="42"}
    {filter field="tracker_field_procedurePage" content="{{page}}"}
    {filter field="tracker_field_userLogin" content="{{user}}"}
    {OUTPUT()}~tc~Item found, so already done~/tc~You already did this bit{OUTPUT}
    {ALTERNATE()}~tc~Nothing found, show the form~/tc~{tracker trackerId=42 etc...}{ALTERNATE}
  {LIST}
{ELSE}
  You don't need to fill in the form
{GROUP}
```

This is totally untested i'm afraid, and i'm not 100% sure you can use a plugin in the `ALTERNATE` section, but give it a go? If it doesn't work, try using `{display format="wiki plugin" etc...}` which might do the trick - good luck!